# removing the "T" from a datetime when doing a xml+xsl=html with .net (XmlDataDocument,XslCompiledTransform,XmlTextWriter)

Tags: .net, html, xml, vb.net, xslt

what is the easiest way to remove the "T" from the result?

I want the result to be "YYYY/MM/DD HH/MM/SS"

the vb.net code is really straight forward

```
        xmlDoc = New Xml.XmlDataDocument(data_set)
        xslTran = New Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
        xslTran.Load(strXslFile)
        writer = New Xml.XmlTextWriter(strHtmlFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, Nothing, writer)

        writer.Close()
```

thanks!

Comment: What is actually the question? What is the input? what is the processing code? what is the produced output? What is the problem with the produced output (that is not shown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the substring-before and substring-after functions in your XSLT file.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@datetime, 'T')" />
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@datetime, 'T')"/>
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the translate function, to replace a T with a space.

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@datetime,'T',' ')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more readable way of doing it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 10)"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 12, 8)"/>
```

This is less readable but more concise:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 10), ' ', substring(., 12, 8))"/>
```